# Ceiling fan light kit will not work properly

Tags: electrical

I have a four bulb light kit for a ceiling fan. It works great with three bulbs but when I add a fourth all of the bulbs go off. The three sockets used or order doesn't matter; only when I install the fourth bulb.

Comment: What wattage are these bulbs, and is there a wattage limit on the light kit's listing label?

Comment: Also, are they LED or incandescent?